# How can I tell SVN that a file was renamed by another tool?

Tags: svn, rename

I am using Subversion with some files that are managed by another application. I would like to rename the files, but the rename must be done from within the application so that it correctly updates its own metadata. This means that I cannot simply use SVN's `rename` command — the application's metadata will become inconsistent.

So how can I can I tell SVN that the files in the working copy have been renamed by this application, so that it preserves history in the same way as per the `rename` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simulate a "record-only" rename after the fact with something like

```
rename newname oldname
svn rename oldname newname
```

That will preserve any changes that your application may have made inside the file, but allow svn to make the connection between the history of "oldname" and "newname".

Comment: In my tests, this doesn't work. But see the below answer involving TortoiseSVN for a solution.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin and others: first make sure the directory is versioned/added.

Answer (score 7):

You do not specify your environment, but if you are on Windows TortoiseSVN provides a little-known and quite elegant solution for this. Suppose you have a file SuiteSetup.cs that you rename to SuiteSetup-Rev2.cs in your application.

Within either the **Commit** or **Check for Modification** dialogs on TortoiseSVN's context menu, select the old name (showing a `missing` status) and the new name (showing a `non-versioned` status) then open the context menu and select **Repair** move (reference: [Repairing File Renames](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html)). As shown in the figure, TortoiseSVN does all the bookkeeping corrections to convert these to a linked delete-add pair, the way a rename or move should appear.

*[Adapted from my [TortoiseSVN and Subversion Cookbook, part 2](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tortoisesvn-and-subversion-cookbook-part-2-file-operations-and-subversion-filtering/), published on Simple-Talk.com. At the time of writing Part 8 is just about to be published.]*

[image: repairing a file move]

Comment: I gave the tick to the more widely applicable answer, but this is also really good. I was not aware of this feature before!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with current SVN.  The reason for the svn rename command is actually because you have to tell svn what's the rename is about so that it can prepare the corresponding metadata.

Unless svn changes its design to "guess" your renames (like git), or it provide a record-only rename command which perform only update in metadata (which you still need to figure out what renames your application actually done and issue corresponding commands).  However neither of this feature is available, and it is not likely to happen either at least in near future

Comment: It's the latter that I'm after — I know what the rename operations will be, but I need to tell SVN to record them after they're done by the other application.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, SVN cli doesn't have this feature, but SmartSVN does (you select 2 files and press Move).